# How to plot the image tensor returned by tf.image.sobel_edges

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use sobel edge in tensorflow using `tf.image.sobel_edges`.

The following is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import skimage.io
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = skimage.io.imread('table1.jpg')

image=np.array(image)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image=tf.compat.v1.expand_dims(image, 0)

sobel= tf.image.sobel_edges(image)

sess = tf.Session()
SobelImage=sess.run(sobel)
plt.imshow(SobelImage)
sess.close()
```

When I run the program I get

> runfile('E:/projects/Github programs/image recognition/sobleEdge.py', wdir='E:/projects/Github programs/image recognition')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('E:/projects/Github programs/image recognition/sobleEdge.py', wdir='E:/projects/Github programs/image recognition')
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "E:/projects/Github programs/image recognition/sobleEdge.py", line 29, in 
>       plt.imshow(SobelImage)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2677, in imshow
>       None else {}), **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1589, in inner
>       return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5660, in imshow
>       im.set_data(X)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 683, in set_data
>       .format(self._A.shape))
>
> TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 565, 750, 3, 2) for image data

Can Someone help me how to plot the tensor returned by `tf.image.sobel_edges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sobel= tf.image.sobel_edges(image)
print(sobel.shape)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
sobel_x = np.asarray(sobel[0, :, :, :, 0])  #  Sobel_X
sobel_y = np.asarray(sobel[0, :, :, :, 1])  #  Sobel_Y
cv2.imshow("Sobel_x",sobel_x)
cv2.imshow("Sobel_y",sobel_y)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Since the output of the sobel_edge function is a 5D tensor with shape [batch_size, h, w, d, 2] where the last two dimensions hold Sobel edge responses in X and Y direction. Additionally, to display you need to convert tensor to np array first as cv2 cant handle tensor directly.
Output: [click to see the output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4obH.jpg)